Generating a secret key for data encryption Kotlin?
I am working on a chat app. There is a requirement to encrypt the chat messages and save it on a backend server particularly in a back-end DB with a key which was used to encrypt the messages.
There are 2 users Alice and Bob both sent messages to each other and these messages needs to be save in some back-end db so both users can check their message history later.
The model of chat which I am saving in back-end db is like that:
ChatModel(
chatId:String,
encryptedMessage:String,
encryptionKey:String
)

and key is generated using this code:
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(); // cryptograph. secure random 
keyGenerator.init(256) // You can also use 128 or 192 bits
keyGen.init(random); 
SecretKey secretKey = keyGen.generateKey();

encryption is done like that:
fun encrypt(
    textToEncrypt: String,
    secretKey: SecretKey,
): String {
    val plainText = textToEncrypt.toByteArray()

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

    val encrypt = cipher.doFinal(plainText)
    return Base64.encodeToString(encrypt, Base64.DEFAULT)
}

and decryption of Message is like that:
fun decrypt(
    encryptedText: String,
    secretKey: SecretKey,
 
): String {
    val textToDecrypt = Base64.decode(encryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT)

    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7PADDING")
    
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

    val decrypt = cipher.doFinal(textToDecrypt)
    return String(decrypt)
}

according to different searches I got to know that AES is somehow can be consider a strong key and encryption, but also got to know that there are some algorithms which broke this statement like Grover's algorithm.
I am new to encryption and for now I have just this option so seeking for guidance on this so I can explore more possible things for this.

This is too wide in scope. In short: AES is a symmetric-key cipher for encrypting and decrypting data, it's usually used with GCM mode to instantiate Authenticated Encryption which provide integrity protection in addition to secrecy. There're ECDH/Kyber for establishing shared keys, and ECDSA/Dilithium for creating digital signatures. There's also Message-Layer Security protocol that's designed to meet all the needs of chat apps.

We consider concise questions about cryptography as a subject here. Development related questions that seek guidance are considered off topic.

Thankyou @DannyNiu for your comment. I have created an other thread can you please check it.
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/113289/is-it-safe-to-use-aes-encryption-and-store-key-on-server

@User42590 I forgot to mention, we've a reading list. I think a bit of intro on public-key crypto is good for you. Your linked post displays confusion, you may want to reword it after reading my link.
