Is it safe to use AES encryption and store key on server?
I am working on a chat app. There is a requirement to encrypt the chat messages and save it on a backend server particularly in a back-end DB with a key which was used to encrypt the messages.
There are 2 users Alice and Bob both sent messages to each other and these messages needs to be save in some back-end db so both users can check their message history later.
Now I have used Kyber Key exchange for sending and receiving message encryption and key sharing.
But the issue is I also want to retain these encrypted messages in DB. Now for this I have to store the key also that were generated for the chat like the Private and Secret Key.
for this I opt a solution that I will send messages using kyber key but also save the same original message encrypted using a AES key with that same AES key.
So in short Kyber will be used to exchange key and message encryption while transporting and message will be saved in DB with an AES key.
First of all is this the right thing to do so or should I change my approach.
What if I save the first created chat secret kyber key and then save it somewhere in server with both Alice and Bob private keys and then use them for message decryption and on going chat encryption.
Moreover for my approach according to different searches I got to know that AES is somehow can be consider a strong key and encryption, but also got to know that there are some algorithms which broke this statement like Grover's algorithm.
I am new to encryption and for now I have just this option so seeking for guidance on this so I can explore more possible things for this.

If you store the decryption key in three same place as your encrypted data then the encryption is pointless. The usual approach would be to split this into a DEK and a KEK. The kyber exchanged key being the DEK that encrypts the data and then the KEK is used to encrypt the DEK before storing it in the database. The KEK would be a key the user has access to, such as a key file they store on their device or a key derived from their password.

thank-you @n-l-i for your comment. The main issue is that how to retain this KEK if User-A change the device? My main issue is the main Key or KEK which is the source of decrypting any data or key. Means where I should store if if there is possibility of device being change of same User

I'd strongly encourage you to look at existing messaging app protocols before attempting to design/implement your own. Otherwise, this project is extremely likely to have vulnerabilities, although it's hopefully just for learning rather than in production. This is not the type of protocol you should start with when learning about cryptography; offline stuff is a lot easier to reason about. Also, you should be using ML-KEM rather than Kyber since that's the standardised version, and Grover's algorithm isn't considered a problem for AES, especially with a 256-bit key.
